# ReactJS: How do you reset a timer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make my web app display a message for a set amount of time whenever a button is pushed, and for said timer to reset whenever the button is pushed again before the time has elapsed. I feel dumb for even asking this, but how do I make it so that the button that starts a timer also resets it when the button is clicked again? Below is my code so far:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [revealed, isRevealed] = useState(false);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    if (revealed) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      setTime(2500);
      timer = setTimeout(() => isRevealed(false), time);
    }
  }, [revealed]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => isRevealed(true)}>Start!</button>
      {revealed ? (
        <p>
          This should stay showing up if you keep clicking on the "Start!"
          button.
        </p>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the CodeSandbox demo of my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-worker-g9l986?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Start the timer from the click event handler, not from an effect that runs when the state changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set **revealed** *"true"* when button is clicked and when **revealed** is true, click on button doesn't do anything. the solution I can suggest is that set state in a way that every click on button could change it. for example use the time button is clicked. and to clear timeout you should use useEffect return.

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

```
export default function App() {

  const [time, setTime] = useState();
  const [revealed, isRevealed] = useState(false);
  const delayTime = 2500;

  useEffect(() => {
    
    let timer;
    if (time) {
      isRevealed(true);
      timer = setTimeout(() => isRevealed(false), delayTime);
    }
    return(
      () => { clearTimeout(timer)}
    )
  }, [time,delayTime]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setTime(Date.now())}>Start!</button>
      {revealed ? (
        <p>
          This should stay showing up if you keep clicking on the "Start!"
          button.
        </p>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `clearTimeout()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout

Long answer:

Move `timer` to the global scope so this can be used for clearing the timeout and resuse it.

Also, the triggering of the timeout should be in the `onClick` handler instead of `useEffect`. So the button should've been

```
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          isRevealed(true);
          clearTimeout(timer);
          timer = setTimeout(() => isRevealed(false), time);
        }}
      >
        Start!
      </button>
```

See you code in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-almeida-xpm449?file=/src/App.js